# automatic javascript versioning to avoid browser cache clean

Tags: javascript, maven, web-applications, version-control, web-deployment

My web application uses a bunch of javascript files and I want to version them as and when different releases of my app are out. This is so that the users do not have to clean the cache everytime I publish a new js with my release.

Example for `version 0.0.5` for my app I want all my js to be inside `app/js/0.0.5/common/` etc

I am using maven. But have no clue how to automate this kind of versioning. I know one thing for sure, will need a replace plugin to replace all tokens in my jsps to the right version number at build time.

Answer (score 1):

You can force browser not to cache files that may update in future like this:

```
<script src="/app/js/0.0.5/common?nc=<generate unique string here>"></script>
```

so src will be different every time so browser will not cache this script

Comment: THanks. if I change my version number (0.0.5 above) every time, will the browser cache the file ? /app/js/0.0.5/common.js and then /app/js/0.0.6/common.js etc.. will the browser be forced to use the latest one or will it used the cached one ?

Comment: Browser will use the latest one, because url changed in your case too